# не работает selected in option vue.js

Tags: vue.js

//Нужно выбрать все роли из списка которые есть у данного пользователя

```html
<template>
 <select v-model="employee.roles.roles"
   <option v-for="option_role in options_roles" :value="option_role.slug" :selected="hasRole(option_role.slug)">
      {{option_role.name}}
   </option>
 </select>
</template>
<script>
   data() {
     return {
        employee:{
          roles:{
            roles: []//данные приходят с сервера
          }
        },
        //Все роли
        options_roles:[
                   {
                       slug: 'manager',
                       name: 'Менеджер'
                   },
                   {
                       slug: 'seller',
                       name: 'Продавец'
                   },
               ],
    }
   },
   methods: {
     hasRole(role){
        const roles = this.employee.roles.roles

        for (const roleKey in roles) {
            if (roles[roleKey].slug === role){
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    },
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Не видно, что именно приходит с сервера и как эти данные обрабатываются.

Comment: Виктор Карев
 данные все на месте не выбирает select который совпадает пишут что  он как то v-model игнорирует начальное значение атрибутов value, checked или selected на любых элементах форм. Данные экземпляра Vue всегда считаются источником истины. Начальное значение необходимо объявить на стороне JavaScript, внутри опции data компонента. но как это решить тогда?

Comment: Какой формат у employee.roles.roles? Это массив чего? Судя по использованию в v-model, это должен быть массив строк, а судя по функции hasRole - массив объектов. А на самом деле?

Comment: такой самый как и options[
                {
                    slug: 'manager',
                    name: 'Менеджер'
                },
                {
                    slug: 'seller',
                    name: 'Продавец'
                },
            ],

Comment: Для v-model такой формат не годится. Из-за этого элемент <select> будет отображаться в «невыбранном» состоянии.

Comment: ну а какой тогда?

Comment: Для <select> с множественным выбором - такой: ['manager', 'seller'].